# How to force update a grid thats created by ForEach with just Int?

Tags: swiftui

I have made this "chessboard" of blank colors, which every second one of the squares should get filled with a random color. To do this i have filled the grid with blank colors. Every second one of them should get assigned a new color, and the grid should be redrawn. Not sure how i "force" SwiftUI to do this update for the given code:

```
struct AnimationObject: Hashable, Equatable {
    var hashValue: Int {
        return self.placement.0.hashValue + self.placement.1.hashValue
    }
    static func == (lhs: AnimationObject, rhs: AnimationObject) -> Bool {
        return lhs.placement == rhs.placement
    }
    
    
    var color: Color
    let placement: (Int, Int)
    
    static func emptyArray(rows: Int, colums: Int) -> [AnimationObject] {
        var emptyArray = [AnimationObject]()
        for i in 0...rows {
            for k in 0...colums {
                emptyArray.append(.init(color: .clear, placement: (i,k)))
            }
        }
        return emptyArray
    }
}


struct AnimatedCanvas: View {
    
    @State var colors = AnimationObject.emptyArray(rows: 4, colums: 4)
    
    let size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        Grid(horizontalSpacing: 0, verticalSpacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0..<4) { i in
                ForEach(0..<4) { j in
                    let color = colors.filter { $0.placement.0 == i && $0.placement.1 == j}.first!
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(color.color)
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                }
            }.padding(0)
            
        }.onReceive(timer) { input in
            let i = Int.random(in: 0..<4)
            let j = Int.random(in: 0..<4)
            var color = colors.filter { $0.placement.0 == i && $0.placement.1 == j}.first!
            color.color = Color.random()
            if colors.count > 30 {
                colors.removeAll()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SwiftUI depends on Hashable to determine when to redraw, you are effectively telling SwiftUI to only redraw when the placement changes which never will because it is a “let”. 1. Don’t override Hashable unless you have a really good reason and know what is going on. 2. Color is a View, don’t put it in a model, use UIColor instead or some other representation of color data. You should watch “Demystify SwiftUI”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two problems with the code you posted:

1. To update a cell color, you said this:

   ```
   var color = colors.filter { $0.placement.0 == i && $0.placement.1 == j}.first!
   color.color = Color.random()
   ```

   The code above creates a *copy* of an `AnimationObject` from the `colors` array, and modifies the copy. It doesn't modify any of the original objects in the `colors` array, so the `body` doesn't have any new colors to draw.

   (If you come from a language like Java or C#, this behavior may be difficult to understand.)
2. You don't use `GridRow` to group `Rectangle`s into rows, so `Grid` creates a single vertical stack of 16 `Rectangle`s.

Let's rewrite the code. First, to make sure it compiles, we need to provide a `Color.random` method:

```
extension Color {
    static func random() -> Self {
        return Color(
            Color.RGBColorSpace.sRGBLinear,
            red: Double.random(in: 0...1),
            green: Double.random(in: 0...1),
            blue: Double.random(in: 0...1),
            opacity: 1
        )
    }
}
```

Next, instead of storing an array of objects that hold both a `Color` and a  placement, let's create a type that acts like a two-dimensional array of `Color`:

```
struct ColorGrid {
    let width: Int
    let height: Int
    private var storage: [Color]
    
    init(width: Int, height: Int) {
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        storage = .init(repeating: .clear, count: width * height)
    }
    
    subscript(x: Int, y: Int) -> Color {
        get { storage[index(x: x, y: y)] }
        set { storage[index(x: x, y: y)] = newValue }
    }
    
    private func index(x: Int, y: Int) -> Int {
        precondition((0 ..< width).contains(x))
        precondition((0 ..< height).contains(y))
        return width * y + x
    }
}
```

Let's add a method that randomizes the color of one cell:

```
extension ColorGrid {
    mutating func randomizeOneCell() {
        let x = (0 ..< width).randomElement()!
        let y = (0 ..< height).randomElement()!
        self[x, y] = Color.random()
    }
}
```

Finally, we're ready to put the pieces together to draw the grid and randomize a cell periodically:

```
struct AnimatedCanvas: View {
    @State var colors = ColorGrid(width: 4, height: 4)

    var body: some View {
        Grid(horizontalSpacing: 0, verticalSpacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0 ..< colors.height, id: \.self) { y in
                GridRow {
                    ForEach(0 ..< colors.width, id: \.self) { x in
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(colors[x, y])
                            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            while true {
                do { try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1)) }
                catch { return }
                colors.randomizeOneCell()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result (I only recorded a few seconds of it):

[image: demo of a 4x4 grid that starts out all white. Each second, a random grid cell becomes a random color.]